# how to find if particular objects exists in array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array

```
let bingo = [{"Device": "fan", "Manafacturer": "Havells"}, {"Device": "Ceiling", "Manafacturer": "bajaj"}]
```

how to check if particular object exists
in this case let it be

```
let obj ={"Device": "Ceiling", "Manafacturer": "bajaj"}
//should return true or {"Device": "Ceiling", "Manafacturer": "bajaj"}

 obj ={"Device": "light", "Manafacturer": "bajaj"}
//should return false or undefined
```

Comment: [Array find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Comment: or [Array.Includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

Comment: Typo: Manufacturer

Comment: All of which are readily available in the MDN documentation.  You should avail yourself of it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think `.includes` will work unless the reference is identical.

Comment: It's possible.  I suspect that's also in the documentation.

Comment: THREE answers so far... edit: down to two

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript Arrays have a function called `find`, which returns all elements of an array, that match the condition:

```js
let bingo = [{
  "Device": "fan",
  "Manafacturer": "Havells"
}, {
  "Device": "Ceiling",
  "Manafacturer": "bajaj"
}];
let obj = {
  "Device": "Ceiling",
  "Manafacturer": "bajaj"
};

let result = bingo.find(bingoObj => bingoObj.Manafacturer === obj.Manafacturer);

console.log(result);
// logs {"Device": "Ceiling", "Manafacturer": "bajaj"}
```

see https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find for further reference on the find function

Comment: The chance of this not being a dupe is basically zero.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert it to a string and then use `indexOf()` to check if it is included. This would also be useful for nested complex objects. Keys must be in the same order or it would fail, as commented by Lain:

```js
let bingo = [{"Device": "fan", "Manafacturer": "Havells"}, {"Device": "Ceiling", "Manafacturer": "bajaj"}];

let check1 ={"Device": "Ceiling", "Manafacturer": "bajaj"}
//should return true or {"Device": "Ceiling", "Manafacturer": "bajaj"}

let check2 ={"Device": "light", "Manafacturer": "bajaj"}
//should return false or undefined

function checkObjectExists(main, check) {
  return JSON.stringify(main).indexOf(JSON.stringify(check)) >= 0;
}

console.log( checkObjectExists(bingo, check1) );   //true

console.log( checkObjectExists(bingo, check2) );  //false
```

Comment: The chance of this not being a dupe is basically zero.

Comment: One just has to change the order of keys in `obj` to make it fail.

Answer (score 0):

You could either pass in an object, where you check each key-value pair of the criteria; or you pass in a function, where you access value of each item and check them for comparison.

Without strict checking, each item will just be serialized into JSON and compares with a JSON criteria value. This is the least optimal way to check.

```js
const assertTrue  = (v) => { if (v !== true)  throw new Error('value is not true');  };
const assertFalse = (v) => { if (v !== false) throw new Error('value is not false'); };

const arrayContains = (arr, criteria, strict = true) => arr.find(item =>
  typeof criteria === 'function'
    ? criteria(item)
    : strict
      ? Object.entries(criteria).every(([k, v]) => (item[k] === v))
      : JSON.stringify(item) === JSON.stringify(criteria)
    ) != null

const bingo = [
  { "Device": "fan"     , "Manufacturer": "Havells" },
  { "Device": "Ceiling" , "Manufacturer": "bajaj"   }
];

let found = arrayContains(bingo, { "Device": "Ceiling", "Manufacturer": "bajaj" });
assertTrue(found);

found = arrayContains(bingo, ({ Device, Manufacturer }) =>
  Device === 'Ceiling' && Manufacturer === 'bajaj');
assertTrue(found);

found = arrayContains(bingo, { "Device": "light", "Manufacturer": "bajaj" });
assertFalse(found);

console.log('Testing complete...');
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```